# Printing Reversed Linked List Using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

i'm trying to print a linked list in reverse order without actually reversing it using recursion but my output is coming out very weird. It seems like my code basically picks the first node and prints it after the rest of linked list has been printed (in it's original order). The code i've written is (as far as i can see) correct and matches with the code for this problem on the internet.

here's my code:

```
public class PrintLinkedListRecursively {

public static void printReverse(Node<Integer> temp) {
    if(temp == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    print(temp.next);
    System.out.print(temp.data);
    
}

public static Node<Integer> input() {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int data = scn.nextInt();
    Node<Integer> head = null, tail = null;
    
    while(data!=-1) {
        Node<Integer> currentNode = new Node<Integer>(data);
        if(head == null) {
            head = currentNode;
            tail = currentNode;
        }else {
            tail.next = currentNode;
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        
        data = scn.nextInt();
    }
    
    return head;
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Node<Integer> head = input();
    printReverse(head);

}
}
```

here's the Node class:

```
public class Node<T> {

T data;
Node<T> next;

Node(T data){
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

this is the input i gave, followed by the output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 -1
2 3 4 5 1
```

Another weird thing happening here is, if i change the condition for coming out of recursion, say if i do this:

```
if(temp.next.next.next == null){
   return;
}
```

and then followed by the rest of the original code, it's literally still giving me the same output. Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Comment: In the `printReverse` method, you should call `printReverse(temp.next)` instead of `print(temp.next)`.

Comment: Be careful with conditions like `temp.next.next.next == null` - this is fragile (you could get an NPE for everything along `temp.next.next` already, what if there are less than 3 elements in the list, etc.?), hard to understand (e.g. why 3x `next`?) and probably not necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo, because Asker thinks they do recursion, but they don't: they call the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the `printReverse()` function as:

```
public static void printReverse(Node<Integer> temp) {
    if(temp == null) {
        return;
    }
    printReverse(temp.next);
    System.out.print(temp.data);
}
```